# Aspectj Table annotation issues

Tags: maven, jpa, aspectj

when I try to add aspectj-maven-plugin inside my existing project, I add this:

```
[ERROR] The attribute indexes is undefined for the annotation type Table
    E:\T2_SupplierPortal_Angular\core\model\src\main\java\com\model\PaymentGrp.java:32
indexes={
^^^^
...
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) on project model: AJC compiler errors:
error at indexes={

It seems that when I add this plugin, it use an older version of JPA instead of JPA 2.1.

My Configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                        <weaveDependencies>
                            <weaveDependency>
                                <artifactId>common-logger</artifactId>
                                <groupId>com.common</groupId>
                            </weaveDependency>
                        </weaveDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I don't know how to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the syntax error in your source code, then retry the compilation. It is probably not even an AspectJ problem, just a Java syntax problem.